# How to draw dotted horizontal line in morris chart?

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I have an [Area Morris chart](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/index.html), and I would like to highlight a specific level on the chart with a dotted horizontal line. I haven't found any examples on how to do this. Is this possible at all?

Comment: have a look at this maybe? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778120/morris-js-dashed-grid-lines

Comment: @Torean: thanks, but that idea is for gridlines, I am looking for an extra line (not part of the grid). But according to the link provided, it seems this is not supported out-of-the-box by morris.

Comment: Ooops, there is support, I had no seen that option: it is called goals.http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html

Comment: haha, no prob man, good luck!